# Solved - Table of Contents: Editing Appendix Prefix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have been struggling to fix this for a while now. I hope one of you could help me fix this tiny issue with table of contents.

1. I want the regular chapters to have a Chapter prefix
2. I want the appendix chapters to only have 'Appendix' prefix and NOT "Appendix Chapter" prefix as shown below.

[image: Problem]

How can I fix this issue? I've tried many complicated workarounds like using \chapter* and manually adding entry to table of contents, but this messes with chapter formatting and further when I link the appendix in the main manuscript, the link is lost. And so I am hesitant to go through the route of complicated workarounds. Are there any minimal clean solutions for me to rename appendix prefixes?

**Summary of the Problem and Solution**

**My thesis.sty file was messing up the format. As @Sveinung suggested, found the code related to the chapter definition in the STY file**

```
\makeatletter \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect Chapter \numberline{\thechapter:} #1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

**and modified it slightly (i.e. replaced "Chapter" with "Appendix") and placed it just below \appendix command of Thesis.TEX as shown below.**

```
\appendix \makeatletter \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect Appendix \numberline{\thechapter:} #1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While you provide a code example which you are working with, it is much easier for the community to answer your questions if you reduce your code to a MWE (minimal working example) by removing all parts of code that are unrelated to the issue you are asking about.

Comment: A real hack in a poorly written .sty file. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

To start the appendices section, you use the command `\appendix`, not an environment. Change

```
\begin{appendices}
```

to

```
\appendix
```

and remove

```
\end{appendices}
```

If you need more flexibility, load Will Robert­son and Peter Wilson’s [appendix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix)-package.

Here is an ‘MWE’ something that at least compile:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,           
a4paper,         
draft,             
oneside]{book}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\fussy
\frontmatter

\typeout{Title}%
\title{title}
\maketitle%
\clearpage

\chapter*{}%
\label{ch:dedication}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage%
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\label{ch:acknowledgement}

\normalsize

\cleardoublepage%
\chapter{Abstract}
\index{Abstract}%
\typeout{Abstract}%

\cleardoublepage%

\mainmatter

\cleardoublepage%
\sloppy

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:Intro}

\chapter[Constrained Motion and the Fundamental Equation]{Constrained Motion Approach and the Fundamental Equation of Mechanics}
\label{ch:Chapter2}

\chapter{Energy Control of Inhomogeneous Nonlinear Lattices}
\label{ch:Chapter3}

\chapter[Synchronization of Multiple Coupled Slave Gyroscopes]{Synchronization of Multiple Coupled Slave Gyroscopes with a Master Gyroscope}
\label{ch:Chapter4}

\chapter[Control of Hyperelastic Beams]{Control of Rubber-like Incompressible Hyperelastic Beams}
\label{ch:Chapter5}

\chapter{Conclusions and Future Work}
\label{ch:Chapter6}

%\backmatter

\cleardoublepage%

\appendix
\chapter[Energy is a positive definite function]{{Energy ${H}$ is a positive definite function}{Energy is a positive definite function}}
\label{A1}

\chapter[Explicit Closed Form Control Force]{{A Closed Form Expression for the Control Force ${F^C}$}{A Closed Form Expression for the Control Force}}
\label{A2}

\chapter[Origin is a single isolated fixed point]{{Origin $O$ is a unique and isolated equilibrium point}{Origin is a unique and isolated equilibrium point}}
\label{A3}

\chapter{{Set ${\Omega}$ is compact}{Omega set is compact}}
\label{A4}

\chapter[Sufficient Conditions on Actuator Placements]{{Actuator positions for which the only invariant set of ${\dot{q}_C \equiv 0}$ is the origin}{Sufficient Conditions on Actuator Placements}}
\label{A5}

   \nocite{*}
   \makeatletter
   \makeatother
   \interlinepenalty=10000
   \bibliographystyle{acm}%
   \bibliography{Chapters/reference}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try \appendix instead of the appendices environment earlier, but it did not help. I think I now understand what the problem is.. I have a thesis.sty template file which is creating all the problems.

Comment: Do you know how I should go about modifying the thesis.sty file to obtain the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Try to load the packages appendix as I suggest. May be it is able to correct some of the errors your thesis.sty is doing. Load it after the thesis.sty. Probably the style-file redefines the definition of chapter command in an incompatible way...

Comment: You have to open the thesis style in an text editor and search for the definition of the chapter-command. Then you have to redefine the chapter-command, and place the code just after you have issued the appendix-command.

Comment: Hi Sveinung, I think I already loaded the appendix package if you see my original post using \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
I'm a newbie in Latex and don't know how to redefine chapter names. Can I post the thesis.sty file somewhere so you could help me out. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Here's a link to the thesis.sty file http://pastebin.com/cBYgfNQn

Comment: Thank you @Sveinung I fixed it with your help :) Many thanks once again.

Comment: @Harsha You had already loaded the appendix package. Sorry for not detecting that.